# DirectX SwapChain with Height & Width not equal to 0 acts erracticly with transparent window

Tags: window, directx, direct3d, direct2d, visual-glitch

I have a window which I have removed the frame by simply returning 0 from `WM_NCCACLSIZE.` I want no border or shadow at all. I then used `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` to blur the window. When I set a custom size in my DirectX swap chain, it acts very erratically. The way to solve it is to bring back the client frame. It does this wired behavior if the client frame is removed. Does anyone know how to do it without a frame?

Normal behavior, but I want it to work without the standard frame:
[image]

These are the erratic ones, I could not screenshot them:
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
WINCOMPATTRDATA compositionData{ 19, &accentPolicy, sizeof ACCENTPOLICY };
    const auto pSetWindowCompositionAttribute{ GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"user32.dll"), "SetWindowCompositionAttribute") };
    if (!reinterpret_cast<BOOL(WINAPI*)(HWND, WINCOMPATTRDATA*)>(pSetWindowCompositionAttribute)(hwnd, &compositionData))
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Unable to setup the user interface.\n" };
    const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[]{
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0
    };
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    RECT clientRect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientRect);
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChain{ 0 };
    swapChain.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChain.Width = 200;
    swapChain.Height = static_cast<UINT>(clientRect.bottom - (clientRect.bottom * .65f));
    swapChain.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    swapChain.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChain.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChain.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
    swapChain.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
    if (FAILED(D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, featureLevels,
        6, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &RootDevice3D, &featureLevel, nullptr)))
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Unable to create Direct3D Device.\n" };
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxDevice;
    RootDevice3D->QueryInterface(dxDevice.GetAddressOf());
    if (FAILED(D2D1CreateDevice(dxDevice.Get(),
        D2D1::CreationProperties(D2D1_THREADING_MODE_SINGLE_THREADED, D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE,
            D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE), &RootDevice)))
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Unable to create Direct2D Device.\n" };
    if (FAILED(RootDevice->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, &RootContext)))
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Unable to create Direct2D Device Context.\n" };
    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> dxAdapter;
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory2> dxFactory;
    dxDevice.Get()->GetAdapter(dxAdapter.GetAddressOf());
    dxAdapter.Get()->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), reinterpret_cast<void**>(dxFactory.GetAddressOf()));
    if (FAILED(dxFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(dxDevice.Get(), hwnd, &swapChain, nullptr, nullptr, &SwapChain)))
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Unable to create swap chain.\n" };
    ComPtr<IDXGISurface> dxSurface;
    ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap1> rootBitmap;
    SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(IDXGISurface), reinterpret_cast<void**>(dxSurface.GetAddressOf()));
    RootContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(dxSurface.Get(),
                                             D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
                                                 D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW,
                                                 D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
                                                                   D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)),
                                             rootBitmap.GetAddressOf());
    RootContext->SetTarget(rootBitmap.Get());
```

This code makes it work as in the first pic:

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
```

This is the code for the erratic pics:

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (static_cast<bool>(wparam))
            return 0;
```

Comment: There are a lot of functions in your code that return ``HRESULT`` you aren't checking. Can you confirm in your code you are checking them all?

Comment: I checked all functions that return HRESULT. All return S_OK